# Can I use linux-2.6.26.2 in fc13?

Tags: linux, kernel

Now is 2.6.33.3-85.fc13.i686.PAE,and I download the kernel from www.kernel.org.
I want to update the kernel.

Comment: But... what for?

Comment: You say you want to update, but 2.6.33 -> 2.6.26 is actually a downgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any kernel you want.  To compile for Fedora, see [this guide](http://www.linuxquestions.org/linux/answers/Applications_GUI_Multimedia/Custom_kernel_compilaton_on_RedHat_Fedora_Systems).  Also, There are ways to compile your own custom kernel from source, with the [Fedora Source RPM's](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Docs/CustomKernel), which are a bit easier to maintain.